# Is it safe to eat poisoned animals?

Tags: rimworld

After a toxic fallout event, most of the animals in the area died.

Is it safe to butcher and eat them? Will this poison my colonists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1.0 Answer

The game has been updated such that animals (and pawns, I suppose) that die with large amounts of toxic buildup are instantly rotten. (I *think* it's anything more than 50% or so, but I can't find hard data about this)

The answer then becomes, **"You can't" because your pawns will never butcher a rotted corpse.**

Answer (score 5):

**It is safe to eat and will not poison/kill your colonists**

This question struck me during my last toxic storm but all the animals died before I could test it.

I recreated the toxic storm with the help of the debugger, built a small shelter for my colonists and destroyed all the current food. Once the first animal, a boar, died, I ended the storm and began the cooking process. I've linked the images of the process below.

I was expecting some stat on the meat or the meal to indicate a potential toxins but there where none. After the colonist/test subject ate the meal he had no negative side effect. I'll be running a test for 2 days in game to see if anything develops. If it does I will post it here but I am doubtful.

[Toxic Food](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhGgV.jpg)
- Sorry for the double screens, my comp is acting up and  I can't be asked to wait 3 hours in paint.